# Create a "while still child marker loop" etree Python

Tags: python, xml, parsing, elementtree

I would like to know how could i create a while loop with the library `Element Tree` in Python which looks like this :

```
while there is still child marker :
    cross each marker
```

Because i have an XML file which is generated by a software but it can be :

```
<root
    <child1
        <child2
    <child1
        <child2
```

as it can be :

```
<root
    <child1
        <child2
            <child3
    <child1
        <child2
            <child3
```

Without the `while` loop i have to do a different code for each case

Thanks for helping.

Comment: You want to *visit* each element depth first? Can you use a for loop with [Element.iter()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xml.etree.ElementTree.Element.iter) instead of a while loop?

Comment: @wwii with `iter()` if all marker have the same name (but not the same depth) i can cross each element?

Comment: Not sure what you are asking, your example data shows elements with different names. - see the edit to my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [Element.iter()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xml.etree.ElementTree.Element.iter) method will traverse an elements descendants depth first

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

s = '''
<root>
    <child1>
        <child2>
            <child3></child3>
        </child2>
    </child1>
    <child1>
        <child2></child2>
    </child1>
</root>'''


root = ET.fromstring(s)
```

Usage:

```
>>> for c in root.iter():
...     print(c.tag)

root
child1
child2
child3
child1
child2

>>> e = root.find('child1')
>>> for c in e.iter():
...     print(c.tag)

child1
child2
child3
```

---

Tree where Elements all have the same *name*.

```
s = '''
<root foo='0'>
    <child1 foo='1'>
        <child1 foo='2'>
            <child1 foo='3'></child1>
        </child1>
    </child1>
    <child1 foo='4'>
        <child1 foo='5'></child1>
    </child1>
</root>'''

root = ET.fromstring(s)

>>> for e in root.iter():
...     print(e.tag, e.attrib['foo'])

root 0
child1 1
child1 2
child1 3
child1 4
child1 5
>>>
```